# Static resource img is not working in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to change the background img of one of the div I have tried multiple ways but not working, below are the code. Please help/correct me.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            1) First option  
            document.getElementById("divId").style.backgroundimage = url('{!$Resource.myimg}');
            2) First option 
            $('#divId').css('background-image',url('/resource/15386ds0004000/myImg')); ==> right click on view file from static resource got the url

        });
 </script>
 <div id="divId">
   // my content 
 </div>
```

> I am getting "url is not defined" error in both options.

This code is working

```
<div id="divId" style="background-image: url('{!$Resource.myimg}')/>
```

Thanks in advance friends !!

Comment: For the first option, shouldn't it be `...backgroundimage = "url('{!$Resource.myimg}')";`. The whole value should be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The url parameter should be a string in the jQuery css class, so your single quotes need to go around the whole value:

```
 $("#divId").css("background-image", "url('/resource/15386ds0004000/myImg')");
```

I wouldn't use the "/resource/.../myImg" URI though.  The value between "resource" and "myImg" is a timestamp -- the last time the file was updated.  If you update the file again, it will change.

Stick with the $Resource variable instead:

```
$("#divId").css("background-image", "url('{!$Resource.myimg}')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your `$(document).ready(function(){});` code firing in the Visualforce page?
I suspect it isn't as currently presented.

There are additional steps you need to perform to use jQuery in Visualforce due to the conflict on `$`. See [Using jQuery in a Visualforce Page](https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page).

E.g. You need something like the following:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {   /* ... Your style changes ... */ }
```

Also, you should wrap the whole url value in double quotes. E.g.

```
document.getElementById("divId").style.backgroundimage = "url('{!$Resource.myimg}')";
```